# preg_match_all doesn't return a result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to parse the string to a dataset through regex matching in PHP.
Here is my code:

```
$string = "?\t\t\t\t\t\t?\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><documents><Resp><gatewayId>g10060<\/gatewayId><accountId>310198232<\/accountId><orderNo>0970980541000510490500480<\/orderNo><tId><\/tId><tAmt>20<\/tAmt><result>1<\/result><respCode>21<\/respCode><signMD5>7ecd1eb9b870aaba3bfa45892095194e<\/signMD5><\/Resp><\/documents>";
preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>(.*?)<\\/(.*?)>/', $string, $arr);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

However it only returns me `[[],[],[],[]]`, as empty arrays. I've tried the regex expression on https://regex101.com/, and it shows me the correct result, but it is not working on my server.

What I want is:

```
[ "gatewayId" => "g10060",
  "accountId" => "310198232",
  "orderNo" => "0970980541000510490500480",
  "tId" => "",
  "tAmt" => "20",
  "result" => "1",
  "respCode" => "21",
  "signMD5" => "7ecd1eb9b870aaba3bfa45892095194e" ]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: dont use regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: they give me a strange format similar to xml, but I cannot simply use xml parser

Comment: that **IS** xml

Comment: It fails in xml validator, how can i handle it with php?

Comment: ``/`` is required for regex delimiters

Comment: `.. <\/accountId>..` - is that actual backslash character in the string? afaik, slash doesn't requires to be escaped...

Comment: to Wizard:  yes, the above string is exactly what i obtain

Comment: someone has solved my problem, sorry for my stupid question, thx a lot guy~

Comment: thought it was obvious that you needed to clean the escaping first. an XML parser  is still a better idea than using regular expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
<?php

$string = "?\t\t\t\t\t\t?\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><documents><Resp><gatewayId>g10060<\/gatewayId><accountId>310198232<\/accountId><orderNo>0970980541000510490500480<\/orderNo><tId><\/tId><tAmt>20<\/tAmt><result>1<\/result><respCode>21<\/respCode><signMD5>7ecd1eb9b870aaba3bfa45892095194e<\/signMD5><\/Resp><\/documents>";
preg_match_all('#<([^\?>]+)>([^<]+)<\\\/[^>]+>#', $string, $arr);

list($_, $tags, $values)= $arr;

// As @billynoah said it's much less code
$result = array_combine($tags, $values);

/*
 * Old inefficient code commented
 *
$result = array_reduce(array_keys($tags), function($carry, $key) use ($tags, $values){
    $k = $tags[$key];
    $v = $values[$key];
    $carry[$k] = $v;
    return $carry;
},[]);
*/

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(7) {
  ["gatewayId"] => string(6) "g10060"
  ["accountId"] => string(9) "310198232"
  ["orderNo"]   => string(25) "0970980541000510490500480"
  ["tAmt"]      => string(2) "20"
  ["result"]    => string(1) "1"
  ["respCode"]  => string(2) "21"
  ["signMD5"]   => string(32) "7ecd1eb9b870aaba3bfa45892095194e"
}
```

Comment: you're right - i was only focused on fixing the slash issue - this is better.

Comment: might I suggest replacing that whole `array_reduce()` bit with simply: `$result = array_combine($tags,$values);`

Comment: oh.. yep.. my fault :)

Comment: Thankyou, this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You need to double escape the backslash. It also helps to use a non-slash delimiter for readability:

```
preg_match_all('~<(.*?)>(.*?)<\\\/(.*?)>~', $string, $arr);
```

Comment: for the record if you want to use `/` as a delimiter here you actually need to 5 backslashes for the whole sequence: `preg_match_all('/<(.*?)>(.*?)<\\\\\/(.*?)>/', $string, $arr);`.  It's a bit absurd - hence why I'd just pick a different delimiter.  glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, regex is not the best solution for parsing XML strings. I think with SimpleXml would be much easier.

$object = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

I've read your comments.
If I were you I would try to clean the XML and use it as an XML.. you're going to end up running in circles anyways by changing the regex rules if something changes in the response. Trim, replace make it a valid XML or .... maybe you can try getting the valid XML directly from the source

Comment: that ``?\t\t\t\t\t\t?\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t`` in my string will through exception using SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: even though I remove that, all the ``<\/XXXX>`` still fail in xml validator

Comment: @user3711105: is it too complicated to write `$xml =  str_replace("\/", "/", trim($str,"? \t"));`?

Comment: You should expand your example to a very simple use case and add code tags but this is the best answer in my opinion.